# Append to the end of the row in file

Tags: java, csv

In my project I am supposed to read a CSV file which contains a number of rows 
and append to each row.
Can anyone please let me know how to append to the row of file in Java programming?

for example, if my csv file contains data as

```
hi,hello,how
please,help,me
```

i want to append after "how" and nothing in the file should be altered..

Comment: Please share your code!

Comment: I think you are trying to use a `RandomAccessFile` !

Comment: See [Reading, Writing, and Creating Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html).  If you have questions beyond that, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of our best attempt.

Comment: It's just text. It's going to be easiest to read it in line-by-line and write out a new version of each line on the fly into a new file.

Comment: i am using csv reader here to read my csv file..

Comment: i have to use the same csv file.. i should nt be using another new one..

Comment: Try using supercsv http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/ library. It's a great library for manipulating CSV files without much hassle.

Comment: for example, if my csv file contains data as
hi,hello,how
please,help,me

i want to append after "how" and nothing in the file should be altered..

Comment: Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Answer (score 2):

Appending a row in a CSV file, is basically inserting text at a specified location in the file. However, you can not simply insert data into a file, you have to read , modify the data and then writeto a new file in the new format. If you attempt to insert data into an existing file, the data in this place will be overwritten.